# Routing in Azure Function in Python does not work

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to modify a route name in my function. This is my code (just testing):

```py
import logging
import azure.functions as func
from azure.cosmos import CosmosClient
import json

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello world", status_code=200)

# Use the @app.route decorator to define the endpoint for the function
app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.route(route="/search/testing")
def get_customers_by_filters(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    return main(req)
```

I have used `func start` and the local host is referencing to the folders name. So, instead of `http://localhost:3000/api/search/testing` the url is `http://localhost:3000/api/functiontest`. Am I using `@app.route()` correctly?

My function.json is the following:

```json
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I routed this with the v2 model Http trigger function. You can see the [terminal output](https://i.imgur.com/rBYvM4V.png) and [browser output](https://i.imgur.com/uuKjbl3.png).

Comment: hello @DasariKamali what could be the reason I'm unable to set the routing? It is not giving any error, it just simply does not work

Comment: have you tried the same code in v2 model?

Comment: use the below code in the v2 model you can route.

Comment: @DasariKamali my functions are currently V2

Comment: Then no need to use function.json in v2.

Comment: Can I share the code in the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I tried the following code in the v2 model HTTP trigger function and routed it.*

**Code :**

```py
import logging
import azure.functions as func

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    return func.HttpResponse("Hello world", status_code=200)

@app.route("search/testing")
def get_customers_by_filters(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    return main(req)
```

**Output :**

*It ran successfully as shown below:*

```
C:\Users\xxxxxx\Documents\xxxxxx>func start

Found Python version 3.10.11 (python).
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5030 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.15.2.20177

[2024-01-20T15:05:21.643Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        get_customers_by_filters:  http://localhost:7071/api/search/testing

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-01-20T15:05:24.391Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '00000xxxxxxxxxxxx'.
[2024-01-20T15:05:36.827Z] Executing 'Functions.get_customers_by_filters' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=2ebe7d56xxxxxxxxxxxxxx)
[2024-01-20T15:05:37.153Z] Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.
[2024-01-20T15:05:37.392Z] Executed 'Functions.get_customers_by_filters' (Succeeded, Id=2ebe7d56xxxxxxxxxxxx, Duration=670ms)
```

[image]

**Output at browser :**

> [localhost:7071/api/search/testing](http://localhost:7071/api/search/testing)
>
> Hello world

[image]

Comment: instead of using the Azure Function extension in VS Code, I've used the terminal with this command `func init <nameFunction> --python -m v2` to create the function and then this worked